# How to replace values by their position in the ordered list of values using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D matrix with float values. I would like to use this matrix to generate another matrix of the same dimension in which each value is replaced by its position in the ordered list of all the values.

**ADDED**

In need to be more specific about the behavior in case of identical numbers. I want that identical number get the same "position index".

Comment: Add a sample case?

Comment: If you have an ordered list of all the values why do you need to replace the values in the original array? can't you just make an array from this list? Your question is unclear without an example

Comment: @EdChum, i want to have "position" and not the "value" (I have edited my question). For example value `3.8` might be the second value from the bottom. So, I want to it to be replaced by 2 (or 1 if counting starts from 0).

Comment: Then you did want my answer.  Can you mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

`np.argsort(np.argsort(A.ravel())).reshape(A.shape)+1`

Which gives you the position (not value) of each element of the sorted array.  But your question isn't very clear.

```
A=np.random.rand(3,3)

array([[ 0.64125557,  0.66146481,  0.82042912],
       [ 0.45543483,  0.868029  ,  0.99365448],
       [ 0.20370261,  0.17365685,  0.13530724]])

np.argsort(np.argsort(A.ravel())).reshape(A.shape)+1

array([[5, 6, 7],
       [4, 8, 9],
       [3, 2, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

EDIT: based on Divakar's solution, which does as asked with duplicates, but reshaping for 2D array:

```
a
array([[16,  5, 17, 11],
       [ 0, 18, 19,  6],
       [18,  1,  5, 10],
       [ 6, 10, 13, 16]])

np.unique(a,return_inverse=1)[1].reshape(a.shape)+1

array([[ 8,  3,  9,  6],
       [ 1, 10, 11,  4],
       [10,  2,  3,  5],
       [ 4,  5,  7,  8]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have just realized that your solution has one feature that makes it not optimal to me. The identical values will have different "position index". If I have 3.0 several times in my input matrix, I would like all these elements to have the same position index.

Comment: @Roman Make sure to edit the question with those details. Also would be nice to see a sample case being added to the question.

Comment: @DanielForsman Guess I got that wrong, as I assumed on per row basis. Nice!